# Correctly Building Fortran Libraries And Using Them To Build Applications

Tags: module, fortran, static-libraries, include-path

I found a few previous questions regarding this, but was unable to find something specific for advice on correctly associating libraries and module files `*.mod` in a Makefile. 
I have a project directory named `project` where all source files for a library are in `project/src`, all compiled `*.mod` files are placed in `project/include`, and static libraries are created into the directory `project/lib` using the following:

```
ar rc myLibrary.a module1.o module2.o module3.o
```

Following this, I create an application code (a Fortran program that uses these libraries) in the directory `project/applications`. I have now, at the root level (that is, inside `project`) created a simple shell script that can build the application. This part is where I cannot get the process to work.

Here is what I am doing:

```
INCLUDELIB='./include'
LINKLIB='./lib'
INCLUDEOTHER=<include directories for other math libraries>
LINKOTHER=<link directories and link flags for other math libraries>
COMPILER='ifort'
COMPOPTS=<compiler flags, currently I use none>
# building the application:
$COMPILER $COMPOPTS -c ./applications/application.f90 -I$INCLUDELIB $INCLUDEOTHER -L$LINKLIB $LINKOTHER
$COMPILER $COMPOPTS application.o -I$INCLUDELIB $INCLUDEOTHER -L$LINKLIB $LINKOTHER -o application.out
```

This procedure does not work, and it gives `Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.`

I tried a few variants of the above from my readings on the web about this, and I hope that it is not some minor/silly error that I am overlooking that is leading to this.

Any help or advise will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the message you get when things were not done right with the library (it's not your fault!).

`*.mod` files are *compiler-specific*, but not `*.o` files : `*.mod` files of gfortran are not compatible with `*.mod` files of ifort. Therefore, when you build a library, you should put all your API functions and subroutines **outside** of the modules. For example:

don't do this:

```
module x
 ...
contains

 subroutine sub_x
  ...
 end subroutine sub_x

end module
```

but do this instead:

```
module x
 ...
end module

subroutine sub_x
  use x
  ...
end subroutine sub_x
```

In this way you don't require the users to use mod files, and you can distribute your library as a `.a` or a `.so` archive.

In your case, the library you use was almost surely compiled with gfortran, so you are stuck with gfortran. The solution is to write another library as a wrapper around the original library. For example, do this 
for each function/subroutine you need:

```
subroutine wrapped_sub_x(arguments)
  use x
  call sub_x(arguments)
end
```

Then, you compile your wrapper library with gfortran in a `.a` archive, and you link it to your project with ifort. In your project, don't forget to call your wrapper library instead of the original library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It helps make things clearer. However, in this case, all the files are libraries that I have coded myself. They are all compiled using the same compiler. I actually think I am running into an issue where I am doing something wrong at the compilation step. Is there anything that you can see could be an issue with the compilation process that I am using?

Comment: 1) Are you sure that the module you use has been already compiled? (the corresponding .mod file exists) 2) Maybe you made a typo after the ``use``. 3) If everything seems 100% correct, it could be that you inserted by error a non-printable character in your source file. Try to delete the whole line where the error appears and re-type it.